# How to convert a String separated by comma in a list queryParam in RestEasy

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I can't convert the String with commas to (@QueryParam) List  with RestEasy.

I followed this link:

https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.0.Final/userguide/html/StringConverter.html

in this part: 26.5. **Extension to ParamConverter semantics**, in the start up the class Provider is called, but it can't pass in the if:

```
@Provider
public class MultiValuedParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
        
        if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType)) {
            return (ParamConverter<T>) new MultiValuedParamConverter();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't localize your issue from the doc, can you post where you find the error?

Comment: What happens when you use this?

Comment: the method is called several times, but never with the expected parameter List class